# Iterating oner array over another in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, sum

I am trying to create a numpy function where it adds all the elements of `second_Numbers` for each of the elements in `first_Numbers`. So for the first element in  `first_Numbers` it will be `(6,10,14)` made by `(3+3=6, 3+7= 10, 3+11= 14)`. for the second element in `first_Numbers` it will go as `(8,12,16)` made by `(5+3=8, 5+7=12, 5+11=16)`.

```
first_Numbers = np.array([3, 5]
second_Numbers = np.array([3, 7, 11])
```

Expected Output:

```
[6,10,14]
[8,12,16]
```

Comment: You are spamming questions asking people to do your work for you, but not showing any effort.

Comment: Sorry i will show more work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: first_Numbers = np.array([3, 5])
   ...: second_Numbers = np.array([3, 7, 11])
```

Make the first array (2,1) shape:

```
In [2]: first_Numbers[:,None]
Out[2]: 
array([[3],
       [5]])
```

Then by `broadcasting` we can add them, getting a (2,3) result:

```
In [3]: first_Numbers[:,None]+second_Numbers
Out[3]: 
array([[ 6, 10, 14],
       [ 8, 12, 16]])
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's the better way to do it but it works:

```
import numpy as np

first_Numbers = np.array([3, 5])
second_Numbers = np.array([3, 7, 11])
L = []
for i in first_Numbers:
    L2 = []
    for k in second_Numbers:
        L2.append(i + k)
    L.append(L2)
print(L)
```

I added the values you expected as an output in a list so you can use them after. This is the result:
[[6, 10, 14], [8, 12, 16]]

Comment: To answer your efficiency uncertainty, run some timeit functions (with more values) to compare this and the accepted answer. The answer will be clear, then for interest, work out why.  :-)

Comment: You're right, I tested this and my code is on average 3.4 times slower than hpaulj's and takes on average 4 µs more than his.